# Is there a way in PHP to get the index of a currently selected HTML <option>?

Tags: php, html, html-select

I'm trying to use PHP to get the current index of my dropdown box.

```
<select name="iface" id="iface">
    <option>vlan10</option>
    <option>br0</option>
    <option>br1</option>
    <option>eth3</option>
</select>
```

The options are set from a loop that grabs interfaces from a server. I need to get the currently selected index if that is possible.

Comment: not sure what 'index' you refer to

Comment: echo $_REQUEST['iface']; / echo $_POST['iface']; / echo $_GET['iface'];

Comment: you should use `value` in the `<option>`

Comment: set the value of each option to the index you want.

Comment: It's possible.. but why though? PHP is server side. This would mean going to the server everytime the selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="iface" id="iface">
        <option>vlan10</option>
        <option>br0</option>
        <option>br1</option>
        <option>eth3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Print selected option"/>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['iface']))
    {
        echo $_POST['iface'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: That will give you the selected value, not the index.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the selected interface is "eth3".
So, just render with php:

```
<option selected="selected">eth3</option>
```

for indexing you render your list like this:

```
<select name="iface" id="iface">
    <option value="0">vlan10</option>
    <option value="1">br0</option>
    <option value="2">br1</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">eth3</option>
</select>
```

Now iface.value (or $_POST['iface']) = 3